# Error al correr un bloque de código de Python en PostgreSQL ¿Por qué y hay solución?

Tags: python, postgresql, plsql

Buen día comunidad.

Estoy intentando correr una PL en PostgreSQL con lenguaje de programación Python
pero al momento de correr el bloque sale el siguiente error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Dándole clic en Continuar sigue y sigue apareciendo el mismo mensaje.

Espero me puedan ayudar.

Saludos.

Comment: EL código y mensajes de errores van como texto con formato. Por favor [edita](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/521078/edit) tu pregunta. También te recomiendo leer [ask]

Comment: Parece que estás teniendo problemas en la base de datos y se está apagando y perdiendo la conexión,¿ puedes ver qué dicen los logs de postgresql ?

Comment: Hola Anthony Sotolongo. Me podrías decir donde encuentro el log de postgresql en windows?